# AngularJS import not working correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to output hello world to the screen, but all I get is {{Hello World}}. I'm just getting started with angular and this is my first app.
I have a js file to declare the app and I attach it to the HTML tag, but still I have issues? Any ideas?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap 3</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="bodyController">
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Tech Site</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Specs and Features</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">How To Videos</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Social Media <b class = "caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu ">
                <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Google+</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Instagram</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">      
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 " ></div>
        <div class="col-md-8 " >
          {{Hello World}}     
        </div> 
        <div class="col-md-2 " ></div>  
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('bodyController', function(){

});
```

Comment: Search around for how to use the debugging tools in your favorite browser. Having the error message helps to debug problems.

Comment: In your bodycontroller add $scope.greeting = 'Hello World'; in your html curly braces change it to {{greeting}}.

Comment: I would also remove the jQuery reference and try to build your apps without it.

Answer (score 0):

`{{Hello World}}` is an invalid expression and is probably making angular error out. To make it a valid statement wrap it in qoutes to turn it into a string `{{"Hello World"}}`

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('bodyController', function() {
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap 3</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
</head>
<body ng-controller="bodyController">

  <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Tech Site</a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#">Specs and Features</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">How To Videos</a>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Social Media <b class = "caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu ">
              <li><a href="#">Twitter</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Facebook</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Google+</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Instagram</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2 "></div>
      <div class="col-md-8 ">
        {{"Hello World"}}

      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 "></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a link to your app.js javascript file.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a plunk for you with your code: http://plnkr.co/edit/QqfkHsZ8A45KFq768Xrb?p=preview

1) The fix is not to use `Hello World` (**with space!**) as a $scope variable, but as one word - `{{HelloWorld}}`. Value inside template `{{}}` brackets is being evaluated by angular and since you can not have space in variable name in JS that declaration fails to work.
Then you assign it some value in your controller, like this :

```
$scope.HelloWorld = 'foo bar';
```

2) to output something in your template (view) you must declare it in your controller. I.e. assign `$scope.HelloWorld` a value, in my example it's just `'foo bar'`, but in can be `$scope.HelloWorld = 'Hello World'` for example.